# Get Gmail All folder IMAP PHP

Tags: php, imap

I want to access the All folder in gmail via imap. in different language and in different name. **What should i do?**

The code of connection is:

```
$mail= imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl} //The all folder should be here ',$user,$pass);
```

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski When we change the langage to french for example, the name of the folder change also; so i need a generic solution for my problem.

Comment: I tried imap_getmailboxes(), but the problem is that i need a generic solution, so automatically it access to /All mail even if the folder name is "Tous les messages".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution i found for the problem.The idea is that the All folder contains the biggest number of mails so we have to get the number of mails in all the folders and then find the biggest number which is the All Folder.

> This solution has a problem when the number of messages in trash is bigger than All folder.

```
    $mbox=imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "user", "pass");
    $list = imap_getmailboxes($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "*");
    $mailbox=null;
    $mailbox_name='';
    $number=0;
    foreach ($list as $key ) {
        $con=imap_open("$key->name", "user", "pass");
        $number_msg=imap_num_msg($con);

            if($number_msg > $number)
            {
                $number = $number_msg;
                $mailbox= $con;
                $mailbox_name= $key->name;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#special-use_extension_of_the_list_command), Gmail supports [RFC 6154, IMAP LIST Extension for Special-Use Mailboxes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154).  That means that the `LIST` response for the "all" folder will contain an `\All` attribute, independently of the language in use:

```
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \All) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail"
```

Unfortunately, it seems like the PHP IMAP library only returns a limited number of mailbox attributes, `\All` not being one of them, so this will only be a viable solution once the library has been updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give me an example of code?
And is this a native imap function or do I need to add another function to my project?

Comment: Not sure how to write the code; I've never played with the PHP IMAP library. This is native IMAP functionality; there should be a function already that issues a `LIST` command, and returns the responses. In the responses, look for the mailbox with the `\All` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the result given by imap_list is not LIST (\HasNoChildren \All) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail"

Comment: But something like that:
   Array
   (
    [0] => {imap.example.com}Calendar
    [1] => {imap.example.com}Contacts
    [2] => {imap.example.com}Deleted Items
    [3] => {imap.example.com}Drafts
    [4] => {imap.example.com}Journal
    [5] => {imap.example.com}Junk E-mail
    [6] => {imap.example.com}Notes
    [7] => {imap.example.com}Outbox
    [8] => {imap.example.com}RSS Feeds
    [9] => {imap.example.com}Sent Items  
    [10] => {imap.example.com}Tasks
)

Comment: @Makram The array of objects returned by `imap_getmailboxes()` have an `$attributes` public property, which may include the `\ALL` attribute (var_dump doesn't list them). I haven't drilled into it to find out but you might start there...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i tried to execute imap_getmailboxes(), look at the result in french:
(0) {imap.gmail.com}INBOX,'/',64
(1) {imap.gmail.com}[Gmail],'/',34
(2) {imap.gmail.com}[Gmail]/Brouillons,'/',64
(3) {imap.gmail.com}[Gmail]/Corbeille,'/',64
(4) {imap.gmail.com}[Gmail]/Important,'/',64
(5) {imap.gmail.com}[Gmail]/Messages envoyés,'/',64
(6) {imap.gmail.com}[Gmail]/Spam,'/',64
(7) {imap.gmail.com}[Gmail]/Suivis,'/',64
(8) {imap.gmail.com}[Gmail]/Tous les messages,'/',64(0) 
Tous les messages == The All folder. but when i change the langage how can i access it?

Comment: @Makram Hmmm, not sure - the attribute flags [documented in the function ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-getmailboxes.php) include LATT_NOINFERIORS, but none of these looks like the extended implementation which includes `\ALL`...

Comment: Unfortunatly ... and the behavior of the function depend on the langage of inbox, i mean it's not always $List[8]->name ...

Comment: And all the `[Gmail]/*` special folders look to return the same bitmask value for `$attributes` (int(64)), so you cannot limit by that...

Comment: Yes. Anyway when i find a solution, i will post it. Thank you.

Comment: The PHP library is fairly inflexible.  You may need to change it or use some other method to get at the extended attributes.  I assure you they are there.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I found a solution for my problem. The idea is that the All folder contains the biggest number of mails so we have to get the number of mails in all the folders and then find the biggest number which is the All Folder.

Comment: @Makram I was thinking of a similar solution - this is an interesting problem.  I can consider one edge case though: users who delete more than they save and don't receive much mail overall. All Mail doesn't include Trash AFAIK and so if a user receives 100 messages in a month and deletes 60, trash will contain 60 until they age away after 30 days while All Mail contains 40. But there may be a way to work around that.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You are right, it's one of the major risks of this solution. Another one is to create an array which contains the All folder with most spotted language like English, french and Deutch. and verify between the imap_getmailboxes and the array content.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PhpImap library, this is how you access the "all mail" folder:

```
$mailbox = new PhpImap\Mailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/All Mail', $user, $pass, $attachment_dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "ALL");
```